# Show that image of three positive numbers under a map have the same properties as the original numbers

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Given a polynomial $P$ of degree at least $2$ with non-negative coefficients. Show that if there are three positive numbers $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ satisfying
>   $$\alpha+\beta>\gamma\\
> \alpha^2+\beta^2>\gamma^2$$
>   then the image of $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ under the map $x\mapsto\sqrt[n]{P(x)}$ also satisfy the above two properties (where $n$ is the degree of $P$).

I tried using induction on the degree of $P$, but failed (I could prove the basis case $n=2$, but could not go through the inductive step. I would be done if I could prove that $\alpha^n+\beta^n>\gamma^n\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$, but that is not true, I saw some counterexamples).

Please help.

Comment: Is $n$ in the root order the same as the degree of $P$?  otherwise $\alpha=\beta=\frac{ \gamma \sqrt 3}{ 2}$, $P(x)=x^{16}, n=2$ do not work

Comment: @Conrad, yes $n$ is the order of $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog we can assume that $P$ is monic (we can divide by the leading coefficient and the required inequalities stay the same). Then $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+..a_0$.

Since the coefficients are non-negative $P$ is increasing on the positive numbers so we can assume wlog $\alpha \le \beta < \gamma$ as otherwise if $\gamma \le \alpha$ or $\gamma \le \beta$, the required inequalities are trivial.

Let $f(x)=1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+...\frac{a_0}{x^n}=\frac{P(x)}{x^n}$.

$f$ is then decreasing so $f(\alpha) \ge f(\beta) > f(\gamma)$

But we have

$\sqrt[n]{P(\gamma)}=\gamma \sqrt[n]{f(\gamma)} <(\alpha+\beta)\sqrt[n]{f(\gamma)} < \alpha \sqrt[n]{f(\alpha)}+\beta \sqrt[n]{f(\beta)}=\sqrt[n]{P(\alpha)}+\sqrt[n]{P(\beta)}$

Similarly

$\sqrt[n]{P(\gamma)}^2=\gamma^2 \sqrt[n]{f(\gamma)}^2<(\alpha^2+\beta^2)\sqrt[n]{f(\gamma)^2}<\alpha^2 \sqrt[n]{f(\alpha)}^2+\beta^2 \sqrt[n]{f(\beta)}^2=\sqrt[n]{P(\alpha)}^2+\sqrt[n]{P(\beta)}^2$

so we are done!